# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource while CORS is allowed in Spring Boot WebMvcConfigurer

Tags: spring-boot, cors, xmlhttprequest

Here is the main `Spring Boot` class. I've configured `WebMvcConfigurer` as below but it doesn't work as expected:

[image: error message in chrome console]

```
package com.nishy.eea1rest;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
public class Eea1restApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Eea1restApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/books")
                        .allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE")
                        .allowedHeaders("*")
                        .exposedHeaders("content-type")
                        .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(3600);

            }
        };
    }

}
```

controller   in my controller I have added cross origin annotations

```
package com.nishy.eea1rest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*",allowedHeaders = "*")
public class Controller {
    @Autowired
    bookrepo repo;

    @GetMapping(path="/books")
    public List<Books> getAllBooks(){
        return repo.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping(path="/books")
    public Books addbooks(@RequestBody Books books){
        repo.save(books);
        return books;
    }
    @GetMapping("/books/{id}")
    Optional<Books> one(@PathVariable int id) {

        return repo.findById(id);
    }
    @PutMapping("/books")
     public Books updatebook(@RequestBody Books books, @PathVariable int id) {

        return repo.findById(id)
                .map(bookss -> {
                    bookss.setTitle(books.getTitle());
                    bookss.setRating(books.getRating());
                    return repo.save(bookss);
                })
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    books.setId(id);
                    return repo.save(books);
                });
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/books")
    public void deleteEmployee(@PathVariable int id) {
        repo.deleteById(id);
    }}
```

The Entity class is configured by Java and Lombok annotations like below:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Books {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String title;
    @Column
    private String rating;
}
```

Front-end side is written with `reactjs`. The back-end base URL is `http://localhost:8080`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Input, FormGroup, Label, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter, Table, Button } from 'reactstrap';

class App extends Component {
  state = {

    books: [],
    newBookData: {
      title: '',
      rating: ''
    },
    editBookData: {
      id: '',
      title: '',
      rating: ''
    },
    newBookModal: false,
    editBookModal: false
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this._refreshBooks();
  }
  toggleNewBookModal() {
    this.setState({
      newBookModal: ! this.state.newBookModal
    });
  }
  toggleEditBookModal() {
    this.setState({
      editBookModal: ! this.state.editBookModal
    });
  }
  addBook() {
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/books', this.state.newBookData).then((response) => {
      let { books } = this.state;

      books.push(response.data);

      this.setState({ books, newBookModal: false, newBookData: {
        title: '',
        rating: ''
      }});
    });
  }
  updateBook() {
    let { title, rating } = this.state.editBookData;

    axios.put('http://localhost:8080/books' + this.state.editBookData.id, {
      title, rating
    }).then((response) => {
      this._refreshBooks();

      this.setState({
        editBookModal: false, editBookData: { id: '', title: '', rating: '' }
      })
    });
  }
  editBook(id, title, rating) {
    this.setState({
      editBookData: { id, title, rating }, editBookModal: ! this.state.editBookModal
    });
  }
  deleteBook(id) {
    axios.delete('http://localhost:8080/books' +   id ).then((response) => {
      this._refreshBooks();
    });
  }
  _refreshBooks() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/books').then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        books: response.data
      })
    });
  }
  render() {
    let books = this.state.books.map((book) => {
      return (
        <tr key={book.id}>
          <td>{book.id}</td>
          <td>{book.title}</td>
          <td>{book.rating}</td>
          <td>
            <Button color="success" size="sm" className="mr-2" onClick={this.editBook.bind(this, book.id, book.title, book.rating)}>Edit</Button>
            <Button color="danger" size="sm" onClick={this.deleteBook.bind(this, book.id)}>Delete</Button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      )
    });
    return (
      <div className="App container">

      <h1>Books App</h1>

      <Button className="my-3" color="primary" onClick={this.toggleNewBookModal.bind(this)}>Add Book</Button>

      <Modal isOpen={this.state.newBookModal} toggle={this.toggleNewBookModal.bind(this)}>
        <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggleNewBookModal.bind(this)}>Add a new book</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="title">Title</Label>
            <Input id="title" value={this.state.newBookData.title} onChange={(e) => {
              let { newBookData } = this.state;

              newBookData.title = e.target.value;

              this.setState({ newBookData });
            }} />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="rating">Rating</Label>
            <Input id="rating" value={this.state.newBookData.rating} onChange={(e) => {
              let { newBookData } = this.state;

              newBookData.rating = e.target.value;

              this.setState({ newBookData });
            }} />
          </FormGroup>

        </ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
          <Button color="primary" onClick={this.addBook.bind(this)}>Add Book</Button>{' '}
          <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggleNewBookModal.bind(this)}>Cancel</Button>
        </ModalFooter>
      </Modal>

      <Modal isOpen={this.state.editBookModal} toggle={this.toggleEditBookModal.bind(this)}>
        <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggleEditBookModal.bind(this)}>Edit a new book</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="title">Title</Label>
            <Input id="title" value={this.state.editBookData.title} onChange={(e) => {
              let { editBookData } = this.state;

              editBookData.title = e.target.value;

              this.setState({ editBookData });
            }} />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="rating">Rating</Label>
            <Input id="rating" value={this.state.editBookData.rating} onChange={(e) => {
              let { editBookData } = this.state;

              editBookData.rating = e.target.value;

              this.setState({ editBookData });
            }} />
          </FormGroup>

        </ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
          <Button color="primary" onClick={this.updateBook.bind(this)}>Update Book</Button>
          <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggleEditBookModal.bind(this)}>Cancel</Button>
        </ModalFooter>
      </Modal>


        <Table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Rating</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            {books}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your front-end side.

The point is that you should concatenate the `url` (`http://localhost:8080/books`) and `id`, with the `/` like below:

```
  deleteBook(id) {
    axios.delete('http://localhost:8080/books' + '/' + id ).then((response) => {
      this._refreshBooks();
    });
  }
```

All other methods are sending the requests to the wrong URL too which should be refactored as well.

**Update 1:**

In response to your comment, you should provide the `id` variable in `deleteEmployee` method in your Spring Boot Controller:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*",allowedHeaders = "*")
public class Controller {

    @DeleteMapping("/books/{id}")
    public void deleteEmployee(@PathVariable int id) {
        repo.deleteById(id);
    }}
```

Comment: I tired. Its saying now delete 405 error

Comment: @NishyJana See my update1. You should provide the `id` variable in your controller, too.

Comment: Oki so. In controller v give books{id} in url. So now should v want to pass http://localhost:8080/books or http://localhost:8080/books/{Id} in the react front end.

Comment: @NishyJana E.g. localhost:8080/books/1 which in this case, 1 will pass as the `id` variable to your `deleteEmployee` method

Comment: deleteBook(id) {
    axios.delete('http://localhost:8080/books' + '/' + id ).then((response) => {
      this._refreshBooks();
    });
  }.             In this method. In url should we want add like http://8080/books  or  http://8080/books/{id}

Comment: Bro it's working. ❤️

Answer (score 0):

You are doing post call in java script and you haven't added that method in 'allowedMethods'

Answer (score 0):

In your browser console, I see an `OPTIONS` call and a `GET` call. but in your configuration class `Eea1restApplication` you only allow `PUT` and `DELETE`.

You need to change `.allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE")` with `.allowedMethods("POST", “GET", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "DELETE")` in your `Eea1restApplication` class.